# Keyboard with multimedia keys on function keys - how to use them?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys, media-keys

I hurriedly bought a new keyboard. It has no dedicated media keys and this is bad since I didn't realize I almost depend upon them (next song was almost consumed!). Despite this, I see that on function keys from F1 to F7 plus F11 there are printed symbols which should indicate something else! Even so, I can't find another key to activate them (Fn key on some keyboards).

Do you think is there a possibility that those keys/functions can be used?

This is a photo:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those symbols on Function keys are the repeat speed of pressed key, how many times will keyboard send information of pressed key to PC in unit of time. I can't remember now how is this called, I think that is "repeat rate".

I had keyboard with those keys and they are activated with "Turbo" key on that keyboard, but how I can see you don't have "Turbo" key on you keyboard. Try Ctrl+Alt+Function key

[image]